# What is the notation for a partial factorial?

Tags: notation, factorial, products

All of this happened so long ago for me, things are a little rusty. I’m calling this a partial factorial because I don’t know what else to call it.

What is the notation for a product of the form:

```
n • (n-1) • (n-2) • … • (n-r+1)
```

For example:

```
n=12, r=6: 12 • 11 • 10 • 9 • 8 • 7
```

I know that it can be calculated as

$\frac{n!}{(r)!}$

but I wondered whether there is a notation similar to that for combinations or permutations.

I am aware that I can write it as:

$\prod_{i=1}^r n-i+1$

but that’s not very compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be thinking of the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials), usually denoted $ n^{\underline{r}} $ or $ (n)_r $, where

$$ n^{\underline{r}} := n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-r+1). $$

Comment: I feel a little better in that I had never come across that term, so that would explain my ignorance. I notice that there some ambiguity regarding notation, but at least I now have simple way to write it. I have also recently discovered the use of _Tex_ markup, so I can write the following: $\frac{n!}{r!} \equiv n^{\underline{r}} \equiv (n)_r$